# Where to syncronize inside a Java WebApp

Tags: java, web-applications, synchronization

My employer has currently given me a project that has me scratching my head about synchronization.

I'm going to first talk about the situation I'm in:

- I've been asked to create a pdf-report/quotation-tool that takes data (from csv-files; because the actual database the data is on is being used by old IBM software and they for reasons (unknown) don't want any direct access to this database (so instead of making copies of the data to other databases, they apparently found it incredibly fine to just create a folder on the server with loads and loads and loads of CSV-files.)), this piece of software is to load data into the application, query it, transform where needed, do calculations and then return with a pdf-file to the end-user.

The problem here is that getting, querying, and calculating things takes a fair amount of time, the other problem is: they want it to be a WebApp because the business team does not want to install any new software, they're mostly moving towards doing everything online (since the start of the pandemic), it being a WebApp means that every computation has to be done by the WebApp and getting the data likewise.

My question: Is each call to a servlet by a separate user treated as a separate servlet and should I only synchronize the methods on the business logic (getting and using the data); or should I write some code that puts itself in the middle of the servlet, receives a user-id (as reference), that then  runs the business-logic in a synchronized-fashion, then receiving data and returning the pdf-file?

(I hope you get the gist of it...)
Everything will run on Apache Tomcat 8 if that helps. Build is Java 11lts.

Sorry, no code yet. But I've made some drawings.

[image]

Comment: @NathanHughes yeah, the csv-files are read only; but the question is more pertaining to the relation of the servlet to the other class-files on the server: are servlets for each session treated as seperate entities on tomcat; or do I need to put a man in the middle? Or is the entire webApp each time a seperate one for each user (this would seem very unlikely).

Comment: I first have to get the data, then transform it; all of that is done on the webserver, which returns this data to a page that is viewed by the end-user. So... Wait I have a light in my head blinking.... Sorry light went out again (it's way late here)

Comment: If I had a git repo I could see something similarly done that could help, but haven't found any...

Comment: My idea exactly on the db's (the entire thing would not be an issue if I could just query the data on a database); but my idea is (not saying it out loud)... is that they actually don't have a proper way to copy data from the database. The old software is written in IBM Cobol and has been in use since... 1990. It has been facing a lot of issues. The make weird requests sometimes too. I'm halfway thinking to just get data from the csv's myself, at night query and push them to a seperate database and then use that database. That would solve a lot of speed issues. Will propose on monday.

Comment: Let's hold the discussion here, I'm going to try to make something to get the info from the CSV's to another database first (if I get approval); Then build from there.

Comment: Try to keep your Question brief and on-point when posting here. I deleted some of your chit-chat. And I changed your link to display the image directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With java web applications, the usual pattern is for the components to not have conversational state (meaning information specific to a specific user's request).  If you need to keep state for a user on the server, you can use the http session.  With a SPA or Ajax application it's often easier to keep a lot of that kind of state in the browser. The less state you keep on the server the easier things are as your application scales, you don't have to pin sessions to servers (messing up load balancing) or copy lots of session state across a cluster.

For simple (non-reactive) web apps that do blocking i/o, each request-response cycle gets its own dedicated thread from tomcat's pool. That thread delivers the http request to the servlet, handles the business logic and blocks while talking to the database, then carries the http response.

(Reactive webapps are going to be more complex to build, you will need a non-blocking database driver and you will have less choices for databases, so I would steer clear of those, at least for your first web application.)

The threadpool used by tomcat has to protect itself from concurrent access but that doesn't impact your code. Likewise there are 3rd party middletier caching libraries that have to deal with concurrency but you can avoid dealing with it directly. All of your logic is confined to one thread so it doesn't interfere with processing done by other threads unless there are shared mutable data structures. Those data structures would be the part of the application where synchronization might be one of several possible solutions.

Synchronization or other locking schemes are local to one instance of the application. If you want to stand up multiple instances of this application then you need to be aware each one would be locking separately from the others. So for some things it's better to do locking in the database, since that is shared across webapp instances.

If you can make use of a database to store your data, so that you can rely on the database for caching and indexing, then it seems likely your application should be able to avoid having doing a lot of locking.

If you want examples there are a lot of small examples for building web apps using spring at https://spring.io/guides.  These are spring boot applications that are self hosted so you can put them together quickly and run them right away.

Going rogue with a database may not be the best course since databases need looking after by DBAs. My advice is put together two project plans, one for using a database, and one for using the flat files. The flat file one will have to allow for addressing issues like handling caching, indexing data, replication of data from the legacy database, and not having standard tools that generate pdfs from sql queries. The alternative plan using a database should have a lot less sorting out of infrastructure and a shorter time til you can get down to cranking out reports.

Comment: This is a clear explanation, thank you.